# Access for a particular group _layouts/viewlsts.aspx

Tags: sharepoint-server

Is there any way to prevent access for `_layouts/viewlsts.aspx` to all except a group say `abc_cde`

Is there any out of the box way as well?

thanks for your help.

Comment: for a site or in general?

Comment: @Gwny for a site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to create a new permission level that doesn't have the `View Application Pages` permission, and then assign everyone except group `abc_cde` to this new level.

I did this recently for a project and created a permission level called `ReadNoAllSiteContent`. To create it, I made a copy of the out of the box `Read` permission level and then edited it and removed the `View Application Pages` permission.

Comment: thanks for your reply +1, but in my case this will be very length process, i did this already but was looking for alternate option.